# how can i get inapp browser user-agent?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-agent, inappbrowser

Here is code on script

and i want to get app.isapp = true on this script with change user-agent on chrome

I tried but it seems wrong i don't know how can i

Tried 'mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 15_0 like mac os x) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) crios/94.0.4606.52 mobile/15e148 daumapps/604.1' but isn't worked

```
var userAgent = function userAgent(ua) {
       ua = (ua || window.navigator.userAgent).toString().toLowerCase();
       function checkUserAgent(ua) {
         var browser = {};
         var match = /(dolfin)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || /(edge)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || /(opera)(?:.*version)?[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || /(webkit)(?:.*version)?[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+))?/.exec(ua) || ["", "unknown"];
         if (match[1] === "webkit") {
           match = /(iphone|ipad|ipod)[\S\s]*os ([\w._\-]+) like/.exec(ua) || /(android)[ \/]([\w._\-]+);/.exec(ua) || [match[0], "safari", match[2]];
         } else if (match[1] === "mozilla") {
           if (/trident/.test(ua)) {
             match[1] = "msie";
           } else {
             match[1] = "firefox";
           }
         } else if (match[1] === "edge") {
           match[1] = "spartan";
         } else if (/polaris|natebrowser|([010|011|016|017|018|019]{3}\d{3,4}\d{4}$)/.test(ua)) {
           match[1] = "polaris";
         }
 
         browser[match[1]] = true;
         browser.name = match[1];
         browser.version = setVersion(match[2]);
 
         return browser;
       }
 
       function setVersion(versionString) {
         var version = {};
 
         var versions = versionString ? versionString.split(/\.|-|_/) : ["0", "0", "0"];
         version.info = versions.join(".");
         version.major = versions[0] || "0";
         version.minor = versions[1] || "0";
         version.patch = versions[2] || "0";
 
         return version;
       }
 
       function checkPlatform(ua) {
         if (isPc(ua)) {
           return "pc";
         } else if (isTablet(ua)) {
           return "tablet";
         } else if (isMobile(ua)) {
           return "mobile";
         } else {
           return "";
         }
       }
 
       function isPc(ua) {
         if (ua.match(/linux|windows (nt|98)|macintosh/) && !ua.match(/android|mobile|polaris|lgtelecom|uzard|natebrowser|ktf;|skt;/)) {
           return true;
         }
         return false;
       }
 
       function isTablet(ua) {
         if (ua.match(/ipad/) || ua.match(/android/) && !ua.match(/mobi|mini|fennec/)) {
           return true;
         }
         return false;
       }
 
       function isMobile(ua) {
         if (!!ua.match(/ip(hone|od)|android.+mobile|windows (ce|phone)|blackberry|bb10|symbian|webos|firefox.+fennec|opera m(ob|in)i|polaris|iemobile|lgtelecom|nokia|sonyericsson|dolfin|uzard|natebrowser|ktf;|skt;/)) {
           return true;
         } else {
           return false;
         }
       }
 
       function checkOs(ua) {
         var os = {},
             match = /(iphone|ipad|ipod)[\S\s]*os ([\w._\-]+) like/.exec(ua) || /(android)[ \/]([\w._\-]+);/.exec(ua) || (/android/.test(ua) ? ["", "android", "0.0.0"] : false) || (/polaris|natebrowser|([010|011|016|017|018|019]{3}\d{3,4}\d{4}$)/.test(ua) ? ["", "polaris", "0.0.0"] : false) || /(windows)(?: nt | phone(?: os){0,1} | )([\w._\-]+)/.exec(ua) || (/(windows)/.test(ua) ? ["", "windows", "0.0.0"] : false) || /(mac) os x ([\w._\-]+)/.exec(ua) || (/(linux)/.test(ua) ? ["", "linux", "0.0.0"] : false) || (/webos/.test(ua) ? ["", "webos", "0.0.0"] : false) || /(bada)[ \/]([\w._\-]+)/.exec(ua) || (/bada/.test(ua) ? ["", "bada", "0.0.0"] : false) || (/(rim|blackberry|bb10)/.test(ua) ? ["", "blackberry", "0.0.0"] : false) || ["", "unknown", "0.0.0"];
 
         if (match[1] === "iphone" || match[1] === "ipad" || match[1] === "ipod") {
           match[1] = "ios";
         } else if (match[1] === "windows" && match[2] === "98") {
           match[2] = "0.98.0";
         }
         os[match[1]] = true;
         os.name = match[1];
         os.version = setVersion(match[2]);
         return os;
       }
 
       function checkApp(ua) {
         var app = {},
             match = /(crios)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || /(daumapps)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || ["", ""];
 
         if (match[1]) {
           app.isApp = true;
           app.name = match[1];
           app.version = setVersion(match[2]);
         } else {
           app.isApp = false;
         }
 
         return app;
       }
 
       return {
         ua: ua,
         browser: checkUserAgent(ua),
         platform: checkPlatform(ua),
         os: checkOs(ua),
         app: checkApp(ua)
       };
     };
 
     return userAgent;
```

Comment: Cut down the posted code to just the part that does not do what you expect, and clearly explain what you want to do.